# CSS preprocessor with modules and sane scope?

Tags: css, sass, less

Is there an alternative to [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that implements something like modules and sane global scope?

For example, when I do this in SASS (or the LESS equivalent):

```
@import "foo.scss"
```

...it pushes all mixins, variables, etc from the imported file to the global scope, possibly overriding or colliding with loaded or defined mixins/variables. I think this is a mess.

I'd like to have something more modular. Imagine that `foo.scss` has a mixin `bar`:

```
@mixin bar {
    // ...
}
```

To use this mixin I'd call it relatively to the "foo" namespace. More or like this:

```
@import "foo.scss"

.bar {
    @include foo.bar;
}
```

In other words: instead of working as the equivalent of `from foo import *` in Python, a `@import foo` would really work like `import foo`.

So. Is there a CSS preprocessor that cares about namespaces like this?

Comment: I don't know if it supports namespaces, but look at Stylus http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/, another apparently great css preprocessor (never used it) that you can extend easily

Comment: You could wrap your less file in a mixin (like you would namespace in javascript)

e.g.

.namespaced() {
  // variables don't leak!!
}
.namespaced();

Comment: @LukePage That feature is neat, but you may have two files with the same `.namespace`. For true modularity, all names from the imported files should not be dropped into the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

In LESS you can define your namespace in the file which imports the other.

foo.less:

```
.bar() {
    // …
}
```

main.less:

```
.namespace {
    @import "foo";
}
// To use .bar-Mixin prefix namespace:
body {
    .namespace .bar();
    // .bar(); would throw an error
}
```

Don't know about SASS/SCSS.

Answer (score 3):

I namespace my modules in Sass with immediately executing mixins:

```
@mixin MyAwesomeModule() {

    $fontColor: red;
    $bgColor: green;

    .someDiv {
        color: $fontColor;
        background: $bgColor;
    }

}
@include MyAwesomeModule();
```